# How to create multilevel nested queries in nestjs/graphql using @ResolveField?

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, graphql-js

### Hello. I can't figure out how to create multiple levels of nested queries with @ResolveFiled. I hope for your help.

What I'm doing and Context:

I have a product. The product has a supplier. A vendor-specific product contains product variants. Variants contain options.

I need to make a request in 4 levels:

1. Product
2. ProductHasProvider
3. Product Variants
4. Variant Options

I use the "Code First" approach, created an ObjectType for each entity. Next, I create a "Product" resolver.

Creating a second level "ProductHasProvider" with @ResolveField

When adding a ResolveField ("Providers") - it appears inside the main resolver "Product" and resolves the Providers ObjectType. Okay, it works, I can make requests at the 2nd level correctly.

```js
@ResolveField('Providers', () => [ProductHasProvider])
async getProductProviders(@Parent() product: Product) {
  const { id } = product;
  return await this.productListService.ProductsProviders({ id });
}
```

2. I want to make third level where ProductHasProvider has Variants. I decorate ProductHasProvider as the parent.

```js
@ResolveField('variants', (type) => [Variant])
async getVariants(@Parent() productHasProvider: ProductHasProvider) {
  const { id } = productHasProvider;
  return await this.productListService.getVariants({ id });
}
```

In this case, this ResolveField defines the ObjectType for [Variants], but for some reason at the first level. That is, in Apollo studio, the field is displayed in "Product". I can't query Variants for ProductHasProvider.

```
query Products {
  getProducts {
    Providers {
      id
    }
    variants {
      id
      options {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Expected behavior:

I add a new @ResolveField(() => [Variants]) with "ProductHasProvider" parent (Which is already @ResorveField for Product). And I can do 3rd and 4th level queries.

```
query Products {
  getProducts {
    id
    Providers {
      id
      variants {
        id
        options {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to achieve what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ResolveField` is to be put in a `Resolver`, to specify how to return a specific field for a specific entity.

In your case, you have a `Resolver` for **Products**, in which you specify a `@ResolveField` for the field **Providers**.

I'm guessing that you are adding another `@ResolveField` in the same `Resolver`, and it will specify how to return another field of **Products**.

What you want is to create another `Resolver`, for **Providers**, in which you specify how to return the field **variants**.

Here is how it is working for me :

```
@Resolver('Product')
export class ProductsResolver {

  @ResolveField('Providers', () => [ProductHasProvider])
  async getProductProviders (@Parent() product: Product) {
    const { id } = product;
    return await this.productListService.ProductsProviders( { id });
  }
}
```

```
@Resolver('Provider')
export class ProvidersResolver {

  @ResolveField('variants', () => [Variant])
  async getProductProviders (@Parent() provider: ProductHasProvider) {
    const { id } = provider;
    return await this.variantsService.getVariantForProvider( { id });
  }
}
```

Comment: It just worked. Thanks a lo. I immediately knew that it was necessary to do this, but for some reason I convinced myself ‍♂️.

Comment: Just wanted to alert you to the n + 1 problem that can occur when configuring ResolverField. I share the article at [https://blog.logrocket.com/use-dataloader-nestjs](https://blog.logrocket.com/use-dataloader-nestjs).